# Should I prove the map is bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> **Question**: Suppose $n$ is an even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$. Prove that either every member of $H$ is even or exactly half of the members of $H$ are even.

I saw solution in
[Either all elements of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are even or exactly half of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367131/1048756) 
But I didn't understand the concept because I have not studied homomorphism yet. Also [I asked the same question some time ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742689) got one answer but the proof contained Lagrange's theorem and I also have not studied yet.

**My background**: Currently studying chapter 3 from the book *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian.

Here is my attempt.
**Proof:**
If $H$ contains only even elements, then we are done.
Suppose $H$ contains both even and odd elements. Let
$O=\{x ∈H:x$ is odd $\}$ and $E = \{x ∈ H: x$ is even $\}$ s.t $H = E ∪ O$. Now we want to show both sets contain exactly same number of elements. Since $n$ is even, thus the sum of two even elements of $H$ is even and sum of two odd elements is even as well. Let $a ∈ O$ and define a map $f : O →E$ by $x ↦ x +a$. We clearly see $x ↦ x + a$ is bijective thus $|E|=|O|$ as desired. ∎

**My Question**:
Is my proof correct? If yes , then is it necessary to show that the map is bijective or not? And same for "sum of two evens (odds) is even" ?

Comment: $(4):$ A homomorphism $f\colon G\rightarrow H$ is just a map satisfying $f(gh)=f(g)f(h)$ for all $g,h\in G$. This is all you need. And then the proof from the duplicate is the best one (kernel and image is defined as for linear maps).

Comment: @DietrichBurde the proof from the duplicate uses "corollary of Lagrange's theorem" that $|H|=|ker(f)||Im(f)|$ and i am not familiar with these terms (because haven't studied). Thus i am facing difficulty to understand that proof.

Comment: I understand this. But sometimes it is better to study these things before solving exercises, which actually are meant to use this. I know people who said, I cannot solve this divisibility question, because it uses the concept of a prime number and I haven't studied this. My answer would be: "Start learning what a prime number is first". For group theory, this corresponds to homomorphism and Lagrange (very basic things).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh so it is not necessary to follow the sequence of topics present in the book? And for such questions I should wait for author to introduce these concepts in the book! I should read and use them?

Comment: Yes, I think it is better, first to learn the very basic concepts of groups theory (corresponding to prime numbers and divisibility etc. in number theory). One has to learn them anyway for any further progress.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understood.

Comment: (+1) My 2 cents for your 3 questions: 1) yes! 2) yes but quickly 3) no (rather "obvious"). + Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: @AnneBauval I got it. Yes, I will write more descriptive title next time.Thank You.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understood the whole proof in duplicate. But i have a question, where does the assumption "$n$ is even is used?". And defining function $f: H→\{±1\}$ is bit tricky.